the numbers of lines is greater than or equal to the number of points
Prove that in a finite incidence geometry, the number of lines is greater than or equal to the number of points.
We have Incidence Axioms:
$
I_1: \text{For any two distinct points, there is exactly one line that contains them.}\\
I_2: \text{Every line contains at least two points.}\\
I_3: \text{There exist at least three points that do not lie on the same line (non-collinear points)}.$
Here is one axiom, but I still don't have any ideas on how to solve this problem. Can you help me, please?

In I1, for every two distinct points, there is exactly one $\underline{distinct}$ line that contains them (there could be infinitely many coincident lines that all lie on top of one another).  Every line (even every line segment) contains infinitely many points.  So I would say I2 is misleading...

I don't understand what you mean

Are there any contradictions in the axioms? This is hilbert's axiom

The statements are true but misleading and could be specified more clearly.
